# How to get peer to peer packets data and header?

Tags: networking, protocols, p2p, dpi

I am new to networking.
My question is that .
1.Is it possible to view data from peer to peer protocols?
2.how to get peer to peer protocol header ?

**Eg :In layer 7 architecture
     1.eth
     2.ip
     3.TCP,UDP---> i used tcpdump to view header for this
     4.skype ---> i found using signature and nDPi library
     5.skype-header-data---so my objective is to view application protocol header and data.Is it possible.Is there any way to do that.please suggest me the solutions.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wireshark tool to get more information about the traffic you capture. Take note that even wireshark cannot decode all protocols.

Comment: yup i used wireshark but i also decodes only the common protocols .it doesn't decode deep protocols .but nDPI matches the signature and get the flow of application protocol.so i want to move forward to get deep protocol header and data.

Comment: Even wireshark also uses the basic packet sniffers like tcpdump and libpcap.so using wireshark is useless.